# ReactJS if statement or conditionals inside jsx file

Tags: reactjs, if-statement, conditional-statements, mapping, jsx

i have the app putting names up of made up people.  I want to see if i can add a conditional or if statement to my mapping in Name.jsx. If so, how would i do that?  If anyone can help me this, that would be great!   I would want it to pull firstName and lastName if lastName is a specific name.

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-dream-wtv228?file=/src/index.js)

**App.js**

```
import "./styles.css";
import Name from "./Name";

const PEOPLE = [
  {
    firstName: "noah",
    lastName: "reyes"
  },

  {
    firstName: "elissa",
    lastName: "reyes"
  },

  {
    firstName: "ryan",
    lastName: "fink"
  },

  {
    firstName: "alea",
    lastName: "black"
  },

  {
    firstName: "alyssa",
    lastName: "black"
  },

  {
    firstName: "charmaine",
    lastName: "long"
  },

  {
    firstName: "emma",
    lastName: "johnson"
  },

  {
    firstName: "bill",
    lastName: "johnson"
  },

  {
    firstName: "elouise",
    lastName: "morgan"
  }
];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Name list={PEOPLE} />
    </div>
  );
}



**Name.jsx**

export const Name = (props) => {
  const { list } = props;
   
  return (
    <header>
      {list.map((item) => (
        <div className="peoplelist">
          <>
            {item.firstName} : {item.lastName}
          </>
        </div>
      ))}
    </header>
  );
};

export default Name;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list
  .filter(({lastName}) => lastName === 'long')
  .map(item => <>{item.lastName}</>)
```

will output only items having `long` lastName. `.map` method returns array of the same length as source array.

Comment: would i add that into " {list.map((item) => ( " area?

Comment: I just provided a simple example, but if you've extended your object with other fields why not use them in the output? According to sandbox example, you use this code in your `Name.jsx` and change `filter` condition for your requirements.

Comment: hmm i guess my question is how would i add .filter to my existing code in codesandbox

Comment: nevermind i got it!